# PySpark how to find appropriate number of clusters

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, k-means

I plot elbow method to find appropriate number of KMean cluster when I am using Python and sklearn. I want to do the same when I'm working in PySpark. I am aware that PySpark has limited functionality due to the Spark's distributed nature, but, is there a way to get this number?

I am using the following code to plot the elbow Using the Elbow method to find the optimal number of clusters
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

```
wcss = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)

plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)
plt.title('The Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did it another way. Calculate the cost of features using Spark ML and store the results in Python list and then plot it.

```
# Calculate cost and plot
cost = np.zeros(10)

for k in range(2,10):
    kmeans = KMeans().setK(k).setSeed(1).setFeaturesCol('features')
    model = kmeans.fit(df)
    cost[k] = model.summary.trainingCost

# Plot the cost
df_cost = pd.DataFrame(cost[2:])
df_cost.columns = ["cost"]
new_col = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9]
df_cost.insert(0, 'cluster', new_col)

import pylab as pl
pl.plot(df_cost.cluster, df_cost.cost)
pl.xlabel('Number of Clusters')
pl.ylabel('Score')
pl.title('Elbow Curve')
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

PySpark is not the right tool to plot an eblow method. To plot a chart, the data must be collected into a Pandas dataframe, which is not possible in my case because of the massive amount of data. The alternative is to use [silhouette analysis](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html) like below

```
# Keep changing the number of clusters and re-calculate
kmeans = KMeans().setK(6).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(dataset.select('features'))
predictions = model.transform(dataset)
silhouette = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("Silhouette with squared euclidean distance = " + str(silhouette))
```

Or evaluate clustering by computing Within Set Sum of Squared Errors, which is explained [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-clustering.html#output-columns)

Answer (score 0):

I think the last answer is not completely correct. The first answer, however, is correct. Looking at the documentation and source code of Pyspark.ml.clustering the model.summary.trainingCost is the inertia of Sklearn in Pyspark. In the [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/clustering.html) you can find the text:

> This is equivalent to sklearn's inertia.

The silhouette score is given by the ClusteringEvaluator class of pyspark.ml.evaluation: see this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html)

The [Davies-Bouldin index](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#davies-bouldin-index) and [Calinski-Harabasz index](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#calinski-harabasz-index) of Sklearn are not yet implemented in Pyspark. However, there are some suggested functions of them. For example for the [Davies-Bouldin index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036593/is-my-python-implementation-of-the-davies-bouldin-index-correct).